# Move outer marker on change distance parameter

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have created circle based on **Pin Pivot Center** & **Outer Circle** parameter and i have find **total distance** between this two points using java script.

Now what i want is when i change distance parameter my outer circle parameter should be moved with distance parameter.

So if i have change distance parameter **from 200m to 300m** then my outer circle pin **should be moved 300m from starting point**

I have attach Snap here

[image]

Any help should be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I haven't done any code for moved marker based on distance its only google map marker api that i have used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find outer circle coordinates from this:

**var dest = new google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(start_point_latlng, distance, heading);**

Here, heading expressed in degrees clockwise from north.(Here, you can add 180 or 90.)

You will get new coordinates of **outer circle** from variable **p1**.

For more information, see this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#spherical